# seek results on existence of free subgroup with special property

Tags: group-theory

Are there any known results of the following type?

For $G=SO(3)$, does it contain a free subgroup $H=F_2$, the free group generated by two letters, such that $\forall g\in G, g^2\in H$ implies $g^2=e,$ or $g\in H$?

Rk: see a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614084/locating-a-square-root-element-with-square-in-a-free-subgroup-ii)

Comment: What do you really mean?

Comment: If you do not require $G$ to be free group,you can set $G=HxZ_2$.

Comment: @mesel, you are right, I should directly say $G=SO(3)$ and ask whether such free subgroup exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the orthogonal group SO(3) does contain free subgroups of rank 2. (Read about [Banach-Tarski paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Tarski_paradox) to find why.) However, none of them has the property you want, since you can take roots of any order of any element in the special orthogonal group (as it has surjective exponential map, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612649/is-so-n-mathbb-r-a-divisible-group/612653#612653)). Now, apply this property to a free generator of your free group embedded in SO(3).

Comment: That's because an element of the free basis does not admit nontrivial roots in a free group.