When is $\mathrm{exp}: \mathfrak g \rightarrow G$ surjective?
Let $G$ be a connected Lie group. What other conditions on $G$ are necessary and sufficient for the exponential map
$$\mathrm{exp}: \mathfrak g \rightarrow G$$
from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$ to be surjective?
Is it sufficient that $G$ be compact or nilpotent? What about solvable?

Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924557/if-a-connected-lie-group-is-divisible-is-its-exponential-map-surjective

Compactness is sufficient, and so is nilpotence. I.I.r.c. connected and solvable is enough to guarantee that the image $\operatorname{im} \exp$ is dense in $G$. An equivalent condition is divisibility (plus connectedness); see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924557/if-a-connected-lie-group-is-divisible-is-its-exponential-map-surjective

@TravisWillse, what is I.I.r.c.?

"If I recall correctly"

See also this duplicate.
