# If every nonzero quotient of $G$ is infinite, then $G$ is divisible

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group, divisible-groups

I tried proving this by contradiction (assuming $G$ is abelian, else $G$ could not possibly be divisible):

If $G$ is not divisible then there exist $g\in G$ and $n\in \mathbb {N}$ such that for all $y\in G$, $y^n\ne g$. My next goal would have been to show that, since $S=\{y^n :y\in G\}\ne G$, then $G/S$ is a nonzero quotient yet finite, to complete the proof by the contrapositive. However, all I managed to prove was that $G/S$ has exponent $n$. If I assumed that $G/S$ is finitely generated then I could use the classification theorem for abelian groups and argue that $G/S$ is the direct product of some finite number of cyclic groups of order at most $n$, which would imply $G/S$ is finite.

If $G/S$ is not finitely generated then I have no idea how else to proceed. A direct proof is equally hard since I have little experience with infinite groups. Maybe I am missing something, any hints or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Your claim would imply that every infinite simple group is divisible. But the former are not abelian and the latter are.

Comment: But how are you going to take a nonzero quotient when you have no normal subgroups?

Comment: You should probably mention the assumption that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @anon Yes, if it is not abelian then it could not possibly be divisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are nonabelian divisible groups, even finitely-generated ones (V. S. Guba, Finitely generated complete groups, Math. USSR-Izv. 29 (1987), no. 2, 233–277.). For an easier infinite example, consider $SO(n)$, $n\ge 3$: It is an infinite simple divisible group, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612649/is-so-n-mathbb-r-a-divisible-group/612653#612653).

Anyway, even if you assume that your group is abelian, the statement you are trying to prove is false. Consider, for instance, the additive group of [dyadic rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), i.e. numbers of the form
$$
\frac{a}{2^b}, \quad a\in {\mathbb Z}, \quad b\in {\mathbb N}. 
$$
These groups are not divisible, say, by 3 (I hope, that's clear),  but every nontrivial quotient is infinite (a nice exercise).